# silverlight with javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight

when i m trying to invoke javascript function which is present in my default.aspx page, it is showing some error --> `Failed to Invoke: TalkToJavaScript.`

coding in my silverlight page is--

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this);
        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("TalkToJavaScript", "Hello from Silverlight");

    }
    [ScriptableMember]
    public void UpdateText(string result)
    {
        myTextbox.Text = result;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `<param name="enablehtmlaccess" value="true"/>` in the HTML declaration of your Silverlight object?

Comment: no i have not added...under which tag I have to add this , i mean under <body> or <head>

Comment: @gabe: If the silverlight app is hosted on the same server as the Default.aspx refered to the default for this value is true anywy.

Comment: @Piyush: Can you show us some of your Default.aspx, specifically where you define the function `TalkToJavascript`?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using this approach:-

```
public MainPage() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this); 
    Loaded += (s, args) => {
      HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("TalkToJavaScript", "Hello from Silverlight"); 
    };

}
```

I'm not sure why but I'd be uncomfortable calling back into Javascript from a constructor that I know is running in response to an Application_Startup.  I'm either being irrational or this is the cause of your problem.  Of course currently you aren't showing us the Javascript so you could simply have that messed up.